# Save multipart/form-data on server in objective c but get the 500 response

Tags: ios, objective-c, .net, uiwebview

I have try to save multipart/form-data on server using following code > but does not save but Fiddler free web debugging using save to get response 200 .how to solve this problem

---

```
      NSMutableURLRequest * request=[[NSMutableURLRequest
        alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jsonUrl]
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
        timeoutInterval:30.0];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TPop %@",[Base64
        encode:[[[NSUserDefaults
        standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AuthorizationID"]
        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]]
        forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
      // set Content-Type in HTTP header 
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"---------------------------acebdf13572468";
NSString *contentType= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
 [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// post body 
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data]; 
if (parameterArray!=nil) 
{ 
        NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"]forKey:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"SequencePosition"]]; 

[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image"]forKey:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"MediaType"]];
[_params setObject:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"Hello"]forKey:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"Description"]]; 
[_params setObject:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"car.jpg"]forKey:[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"filename"]];
 for (NSString *param in _params) 
{
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",
        BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:
        form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param]
        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params
        objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 } 
}
 UIImageView * imagicon=[[UIImageView
        alloc]init];
 imagicon.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.jpg"]; 
NSData *image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imagicon.image,1.0); // add image data
 if (image) 
{
 NSString *filename=@"file";
 [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",
        BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:[[NSString
        stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\";
        filename=\"\"\r\n",filename]
        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body
        appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"
        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [body appendData:image];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"]
        dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 } [body
        appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n",
        BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [request
        setHTTPBody:body]; 
NSURLResponse* response; NSLog(@"%@",request);
        NSError* error = nil;
 //Capturing server response 
NSData* result =
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
        returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
NSLog(@"%@",response);
        NSLog(@"%@",error); 
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]
        initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 }
 }
```

---

get following server response

> { status code: 500, headers { "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
>   "Content-Length" = 35; "Content-Type" = "application/json;
>   charset=utf-8"; Date = "Fri, 31 Jul 2015 15:51:01 GMT"; Expires =
>   "-1"; Pragma = "no-cache"; Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
>   "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319"; "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET"; } }

### how to solve this problem...

Comment: Please use code format with Ctrl+K.

Comment: The code is still very hard to read (messed line breaks). Please reformat the code to get an appearance like in the Xcode editor